# how can i differentiate and refer to various UITextViews that are created programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

A `UITextView` is created each time i click on `ADD` button. `Y-axis` value is altered(say, y+=100) every time i click `ADD` and so a set of UITextViews are created one below the other. I cant figure out how to differentiate and access a particular `UITextView`. Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

```
-(IBAction)access:(id)sender 
{     
     int tg=[sender superview].tag;     
     UIView *view=(UIView *)[textView viewWithTag:tg-1];  
}
```

**tg-1** because im trying to access the previous UITextView and when i do this it returns NULL.

Comment: u can set tag value to every UITextViews

Comment: you can easily access different UITextView by assigning tag to them when you create them.

Comment: @bhanu @jaswantsinghrajpurohit i did just that but i cant access the `UITextView` later by, `UIView *view=(UIView *)[textView viewWithTag:tg];`

Comment: what problem you are facing to do this ?  @motox

Comment: set Tag for all textViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store them on a NSMutableArray:
 `NSMutableArray * views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`

Your IBAction

`-(IBAction)access:(id)sender{
     int tg=[sender superview].tag;
     UIView *view=(UIView *)[textView viewWithTag:tg-1];
     [views addObject: views];
}`

Then you can get all the references with a integer index with:

`UIView * storedView = [views objectAtIndex: 1];`

Comment: You depend on the objects in the array not changing their index. But that will happen when you add and remove views. It's better to use `NSMutableDictionary` with the tags as keys in the form of an `NSNumber`. `[views setValue: view forKey:@(tag)]` However I think OP has a bad approach anyway or isn't explaining his problem very well.

Answer (score 1):

Use a view tag to differentiate the views and access them.

You don't say how you're creating the new views, but something like this should work:

```
UIView* new_view = [UITextView initWithFrame(...)];
new_view.tag = generate_tag()
```

Where the `generate_tag()` function generates whatever naming scheme makes sense for your application.

Comment: `-(IBAction)access:(id)sender
{
    int tg=[sender superview].tag;
    UIView *view=(UIView *)[extraCommentView viewWithTag:tg-1];

}`  It returns NULL. `tg-1` because im trying to access the previous UITextView